# How to download image from server and display with fade in fade out animation in swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell, alamofireimage

I want to download 10 images from server using alamofire and animate that image in uicollectionview's imageview..in infinite loop just like photos app on window 10..does anyone know??I have googled out but didn't find suitable answer..Some says to use timer..but I think that's not feasible way.. `

```
if let employeeImage = employeeModelForDisplay?.employeeImageArray {
     self.animateImage(at: 0 , imageArray: employeeImage)
  }  
 func animateImage(at index: Int, imageArray:[String]) {
        if index < imageArray.count {
            self.badgeImageView.alpha = 0.3
             self.badgeImageView.setImage(link: imageArray[index], imageType: .UserImage)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.5, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
                self.badgeImageView.alpha = 1.0
            }) { (completed) in
                self.animateImage(at: index + 1, imageArray: imageArray)
            }
        } else {
               //self.animateImage(at: 0, imageArray: imageArray)           
        }
    }
```

`

I have coded above code in uicollectionviewcell.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code that you've written so far?

Comment: Actually I have use timer with 5 sec interval and animation like this         UIView.transition(with: self.badgeImageView, duration: 3.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.badgeImageView.image = self.imageArray[self.photoCount]
        }, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

**Approach -1:**

Set `animationImages` on `imageView`, i.e.

```
let imagesArray = [UIImage(named: "image"), UIImage(named: "image1"), UIImage(named: "image2")]
imageView.animationImages = imagesArray.compactMap({$0})
imageView.animationDuration = 2.0
imageView.startAnimating()
```

**Approach-2:**

You can create your own animation something like,

```
let imagesArray = [UIImage(named: "image"), UIImage(named: "image1"), UIImage(named: "image2")]
```

Method to manage images animation,

```
func animateImage(at index: Int) {
    if index < imagesArray.count {
        self.imageView.image = self.imagesArray[index]
        self.imageView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
        }) { (completed) in
            self.animateImage(at: index + 1)
        }
    } else {
        self.animateImage(at: 0)
    }
}
```

Initiate the method with `index 0`, i.e

```
self.animateImage(at: 0)
```

**Edit-1:**

To get the `images` from `server` before animating them into the `imageView`,

```
func downloadImages() {
    let imageUrls = [String]()
    var imagesArray = [UIImage]()

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {[weak self] in
        self?.imageView.animationImages = imagesArray.compactMap({$0})
        self?.imageView.animationDuration = 2.0
        self?.imageView.startAnimating()
    }

    imageUrls.forEach { (imageUrl) in
        if let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, urlResponse, error) in
                if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    imagesArray.append(image)
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if images stored offline then it's work fine....I want to download image stored in cache and animate it..not working for me..

Comment: In order to animate all the images, you must have all the image cached beforehand. Otherwise how will you animate the image if they are not present?

Comment: I've added the code for how to handle images when downloaded from server. You can replace `URLSession` with your `Alamofire` API hit.

Comment: And try adding the code that you've tried to the question so we can debug.

Comment: added..please check

Answer (score 0):

try this after you have downloaded the image

```
UIView.transition(with: cell.ImageView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations:
                    {
                        if cell.ImageView.tag == indexPath.row
                        {
                            cell.ImageView.image = downloadedImage
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            
                        }
                    })
```